# PHP - How can I round off the date

Tags: php

I am calculating the difference of two dates like this:

```
$date1= $_POST['dob'];
$date2= $_POST['dor'];

$date1 = date_create($date1);
$date2 = date_create($date2);


$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
echo "<p> The difference is " . $diff->format('%y Years, %m month, %d days') . "</p>";
```

Now, I want the difference to round up, for instance if the difference is calculated as:

40 Years, 0 month, 01 days

I want this to be treated as '41 Years'. Anything above the year will make it to roundup.

Any solutions?

Comment: How can it be 41 years? When it is just a day more than the previous year? What's it you are actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if there is a month or a day and if it is just add one year:

```
//.....
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
$year = (int) $diff->format('%y');
if (((int)$diff->format('%m')) || ((int)$diff->format('%d'))) {
  $year++;
}

echo "<p> The difference is " . $year . " years </p>";
```

Comment: Hello nospor, thank you, that worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this, get days from different of date and divide with 365(1 year),and [ceil](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) (Round fractions up) to divided days.

```
$date1 = "2016-04-05";
$date2 = "2088-05-05";
$date1 = date_create($date1);
$date2 = date_create($date2);

$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
//var_dump($diff);
$years = $diff->y;
$moths = $diff->m;
$days = $diff->d;
$hour = $diff->h;
$minits = $diff->i;
$second = $diff->s;
if($moths > 0 || $days > 0 || $hour > 0 || $minits > 0 || $second > 0)
{
    $years++;
}
echo "<p> The difference is " . $years . " years </p>";
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/Objbe)**

Comment: Dave some years have 366 days so you will have wrong results